# The best practice for RabbitMQ consumers with NestJS and PM2

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs, pm2

I use PM2 to handle each worker (consumer) in a separate process, e.g. `ecosystem.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "Nest App",
            script: "./dist/main.js",
            instances: "3",
            autorestart: false,
            watch: true,
            max_memory_restart: "1G",
            exec_mode: "cluster",
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: "development",
            },
            env_production: {
                NODE_ENV: "production",
            },
        },
        {
            name: "Consumer",
            script: "./dist/message-queue/consumer.service.js",
            instances: 1,
        },
    ],
};
```

I also created a `message-queue` module which includes `message-queue.service.ts` that is used to setup the queue and publish messages, no problem with that.

My structure looks like:

- src

  - message-queue

    - consumer.service.ts
    - message-queue.module.ts
    - message-queue.service.ts

The problem comes when we deal with the consumer (worker), channel consumed correctly, but I can't get any data from the database or call any model/service, my `consumer.service.ts` looks like:

```js
import * as amqp from 'amqp-connection-manager';
import { Channel } from 'amqplib';
import { Constants } from '../utils/constants';

// consume messages from RabbitMQ
async function testConsumer(): Promise<void> {
    const connection: amqp.AmqpConnectionManager = await amqp.connect('');

    const channel: amqp.ChannelWrapper = await connection.createChannel({
        setup: function (channel: Channel) {
            return Promise.all([channel.prefetch(2)]);
        },
    });

    connection.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('Connected from test consumer');
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        channel.consume(Constants.MessageQueues.TEST, async function (msg) {
            // parse message
            // ...
        });
    });
}

testConsumer();
```

Can I query to get any data from the database, call any service (e.g. `authService`), or call any database model (e.g. `userModel`), and how?